# How prove that $xyz+\sqrt{x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2}\ge \frac{4}{3}\sqrt{xyz(x+y+z)}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, radicals, substitution, uvw

let $x,y,z>0$,and such that
$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$,prove that
$$xyz+\sqrt{x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2}\ge \dfrac{4}{3}\sqrt{xyz(x+y+z)}$$

Does this have a nice solution? Thank you everyone.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: SOURCE? ${}{}{}$

Comment: This is my frend ask me,

Comment: What is the definition of "nice"? :-) Do you want a proof or it is enough to prove that it has a nice solution? :-) If you gave us some motivation of the validity (instead of my friend said) and described how did you mean nice, it would be helpful.

Comment: This inequality is so sharp, I can't think a way without using Lagrange multipliers so that you don't magnify too much/too little...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is neither nice nor complete. At the end, I still need to plot a very complicated function in one variable to conclude the inequality is true.
In any event, here is my attempt.

Let $a,b,c$ be the three elementary symmetric polynomials associated with $x,y,z$, i.e:
$$
\begin{cases}
a &= x + y + z\\
b &= xy + yz + zx\\
c &= xyz
\end{cases}  \quad\iff\quad (\lambda - x)(\lambda - y)(\lambda - z) = \lambda^3 - a\lambda^2 + b\lambda - c
$$
In terms of $a,b,c$, the inequality we want to prove can be rewritten as:
$$\begin{align}
& c + \sqrt{b^2 - 2ac} -\frac43 \sqrt{ac} \stackrel{?}{\ge} 0\tag{*1}\\
\iff & ( \sqrt{c} - \frac23\sqrt{a} )^2 + \sqrt{b^2 - 2ac} -\frac{4a}{9} \stackrel{?}{\ge} 0\tag{*2}
\end{align}$$
and the condition $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ is equivalent to $a^2 = 1 + 2b$.

Over the domain of our problem 
$$\mathscr{D} = \{ (x,y,z) : x, y, z \ge 0, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \},$$ we have:
$$\begin{align}
& 0 \le b = xy + yz + zx \le x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\\
& 1 \le a = \sqrt{1+2b} \le \sqrt{3}\\
& 0 \le c = xyz = ( (x^2y^2z^2)^{\frac13} )^{\frac32} \le ((x^2+y^2+z^2)/3)^{\frac32} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{27}}.
\end{align}$$
Since both sides of above inequalities are reachable at $(1,0,0)$ and at $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$,
the admissible ranges for $a,b,c$ over $\mathscr{D}$ are $[0,1]$, $[1,\sqrt{3}]$ and $[0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{27}}]$ respectively.

Notice over $\mathscr{D}$, 
$$\sqrt{c} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{27}} < \frac23 \le \frac23 \sqrt{a}$$
In the L.H.S of $(*2)$, if we fix $b$ ( and hence $a = \sqrt{1+2b}$ ) and consider it as
a function of $c$, it is a decreasing function. This implies in order to prove the inequality $(*1 \iff *2)$, we only need to verify $(*1)$ when $c$ attains its maximum admissible value $c_{max}(b)$ subject to given $b$:

$$c_{max}(b) := \sup \{\; xyz : (x,y,z) \in \mathscr{D}, xy + yz + zx = b\;\}$$

Let us rewrite $c$ as a function of $b$ and $t = \min\{x,y,z\}$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
c = & xyz = (b - (a - t)t)t = (b - at + t^2)t \\
  = & (t-\frac{a}{3})^3 - \frac{a^2-3b}{3} t + \frac{a^3}{27}\\
  = & (t-\frac{a}{3})^3 - \frac{d^2}{3}(t - \frac{a}{3}) + \frac{a^3 - 3ad^2}{27}
\end{align}$$
where $d^2 = a^2 - 3b = 1-b$. Notice $\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = 3 (t - \frac{a}{3})^2 - \frac{d^2}{3}$. One can verify $c$ achieves its maximum at $t = \frac{a - d}{3}$. As a result, we get:

$$\begin{align} 
& c_{max}(b) = -\frac{d^3}{27} + \frac{d^3}{9} + \frac{a^3 - 3ad^2}{27}
= \frac{2 d^3 + a^3 - 3ad^2}{27}
= \frac{(a+2d)(a-d)^2}{27}\\
\implies & a c_{max}(b) = \frac{( (a+d)^2 - d^2 )(a - d)^2}{27}
= \frac{b^2}{3}( 1 - L(b) )
\end{align}$$
where 
$$L(b) = \left( \frac{d}{a+d} \right)^2 = \frac{1-b}{(\sqrt{1+2b}+\sqrt{1-b})^2}$$
In terms of $b$ and $L(b)$, the inequality $(*1)$ at $c = c_{max}(b)$ becomes:

$$
\frac{b^2}{3\sqrt{1+2b}}(1 - L(b)) + \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{3}(1 + 2L(b))} 
- \frac43 \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{3}( 1 - L(b) )} \stackrel{?}{\ge} 0\tag{*3}
$$

I don't know how to simplify this further but the plot below show that it is true for all $b \in [0,1]$.

[image: 100 x LHS of (*3)]

So the inequality at hand is indeed true. In fact the inequality is strict except when
$$\begin{cases}
b = 0, &\iff  (x,y,z) = (1,0,0) \text{ or } (0,1,0) \text{ or } (0,0,1)\\
b = 1, &\iff  (x,y,z) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} )
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

We need to prove that
$$xyz+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2)}\geq\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{xyz(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}.$$

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where
$$f(w^3)=w^3+3\sqrt{(3u^2-2v^2)(3v^4-2uw^3)}-4\sqrt{u(3u^2-2v^2)w^3}.$$
But by AM-GM
$$f'(w^3)=1-\frac{3u\sqrt{3u^2-2v^2}}{\sqrt{3v^4-2uw^3}}-2\sqrt{\frac{u(3u^2-2v^2)}{w^3}}\leq1-\sqrt{\frac{u(3u^2-2v^2)}{w^3}}\leq0,$$
which says that $f$ is a decreasing function and it's enough to prove our inequality

for a maximal value of $w^3$, which happens for equality case of two variables.

Since our inequality is homogeneous, it's enough to do it for $y=z=1$, which gives
$$x+\sqrt{(x^2+2)(2x^2+1)}\geq\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{x(x+2)(x^2+2)}$$ or after squaring of the both sides
$$x^4-16x^3+11x^2-32x+9+9x\sqrt{(x^2+2)(2x^2+1)}\geq0.$$
Now, by C-S $$\sqrt{(x^2+2)(2x^2+1)}=\sqrt{(x^2+1+1)(x^2+x^2+1)}\geq x^2+x+1.$$
Id est, it remains to prove that
$$x^4-16x^3+11x^2-32x+9+9x(x^2+x+1)\geq0$$ or
$$(x-1)^2(x^2-5x+9)\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

*A proof using the pqr method*:

Let $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$.

The condition $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$
becomes $p^2 - 2q = 1$.
Thus, $q = \frac{p^2 - 1}{2}$.
Since $q \ge 0$, we have $p\ge 1$.
Using $p^2 \ge 3q$, we have $p \le \sqrt 3$.
Thus, $1 \le p \le \sqrt 3$.

The desired inequality is written as
$$r + \sqrt{q^2 - 2pr} \ge \frac43\sqrt{pr}$$
or
$$r\sqrt 3 + \sqrt{3(q^2 - 2pr)} \ge \frac43\sqrt{3pr}$$
or
$$r\sqrt 3 + (\sqrt{3(q^2 - 2pr)} - q)
+ \frac43(q - \sqrt{3pr}) - \frac{q}3\ge 0$$
or
$$r\sqrt 3 + \frac{2(q^2 - 3pr)}{\sqrt{3(q^2 - 2pr)} + q}
+ \frac43 \cdot \frac{q^2 - 3pr}{q + \sqrt{3pr}} - \frac{q}3 \ge 0. \tag{1}$$

From (1), using $\sqrt{3(q^2 - 2pr)} \le \sqrt{3q^2} \le \frac74 q$ and $q^2 \ge 3pr$ , it suffices to prove that
$$r\sqrt 3 + \frac{2(q^2 - 3pr)}{\frac74 q + q}
+ \frac43 \cdot \frac{q^2 - 3pr}{q + q} - \frac{q}3 \ge 0$$
or
$$35q^2 \ge (138p - 33\sqrt 3\, q)r . \tag{2}$$
The proof of (2) is given at the end.

We are done.

---

*Proof of (2)*:

Note that
$$0 \le (x - y)^2(y -z)^2(z-x)^2
= -27r^2 + (-4p^3 + 18pq)r + p^2q^2 - 4q^3$$
which results in
$$r \le - \frac{2}{27}p^3 + \frac13 pq
+ \frac{2}{27}(p^2 - 3q)\sqrt{p^2 - 3q}.\tag{3}$$

From (2) and (3), using
$138p - 33\sqrt 3\, q
= 138p - 33\sqrt 3\, \cdot \frac{p^2 - 1}{2} > 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$35q^2 \ge (138p - 33\sqrt 3\, q)\cdot
\left(- \frac{2}{27}p^3 + \frac13 pq
+ \frac{2}{27}(p^2 - 3q)\sqrt{p^2 - 3q}\right)$$
or
$$35q^2 - (138p - 33\sqrt 3\, q)\cdot
\left(\frac13 pq - \frac{2}{27}p^3 
\right)\ge (138p - 33\sqrt 3\, q)\cdot
\frac{2}{27}(p^2 - 3q)^{3/2}. \tag{4}$$

Using $q = \frac{p^2-1}{2}$ and $1\le p\le \sqrt 3$, we have
$$35q^2 - (138p - 33\sqrt 3\, q)\cdot
\left(- \frac{2}{27}p^3 + \frac13 pq
\right) \ge 0. \tag{5}$$

From (4) and (5), it suffices to prove that
$$\left[35q^2 - (138p - 33\sqrt 3\, q)\cdot
\left(\frac13 pq - \frac{2}{27}p^3 
\right)\right]^2\ge (138p - 33\sqrt 3\, q)^2\cdot
\frac{2^2}{27^2}(p^2 - 3q)^3$$
or
$$\frac{-44\sqrt{3}\,p^3 + 1089p^4 + 228\sqrt{3}\,p - 3670p^2 + 2949}{144}(p^2 - 1)^2(\sqrt 3 - p)^2 \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.